# Performance impact due to Nested forEach loop upto 4 levels

Tags: c#, performance, foreach, nested

I have a very unique situation in which i am generating a file for which i have to use nested loops.

So for the current file i have 4 level of nested foreach (). when the data is less its performance is ok ok type still not good but when data start growing the loop grows exponentially due to nested.

Hence it is taking lot of time. Please suggest me some alternative or how can i optimize my code.

Use case:
The file i am trying to print say is having a blue print of the structure which have these nested loop, so i had to go with nesting .

Eg:

---

```
Member Details (Level 1)

    Health Coverage (Level 2)

      Provider Information (Level 3)

        BeneFits (Level 4)
```

---

So Member details which can have multiple Health Coverage in which each health Coverage can have multiple Provider in which each Provider can have multiple benefits.

hope this help with my situation in a real time example

```
Level1
foreach()
{
//do some stuff
//writer.writeline();

    level2
    foreach()
    {
      //do some stuff
      //writer.writeline();

      level3
      foreach()
      {
        //do some stuff
        //writer.writeline();

        level4
         foreach()
         {
          //do some stuff
          //writer.writeline();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Code

In the method used below writeWholeLine() , it again contain 3 nested for each loop, was not able to post the code here due to limit of character of body

---

```
  private string TransactionsGeneration(StreamWriter writer, string line, int maximumCount)
    {
        #region Re-Generation

        TransactionCounter = 0;
        foreach (DataRow memRow in MemberTblMaster.Rows)
        {
            TransactionCounter++;
            line = string.Empty; //begin of a new Transaction
            //Counter
            TotalLines = 0;
            ST_SE_UniqueCode = 0;


            // Fill the dataset based on the member id
            MemberID = Convert.ToString(memRow[MEMBER_ID]).Trim();

            HealthCoverageTbl = HealthCoverageTblMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(MEMBER_ID).Trim() == MemberID);
            Associations834Tbl = Associations834TblMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(MEMBER_ID).Trim() == MemberID);
            AddressTbl = AddressTblMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(MEMBER_ID).Trim() == MemberID);
            GenNameInfoTbl = GenNameInfoTblMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(Gen_Name_ID).Trim() == memRow[Sponsor_ID].ToString().Trim() ||
                                                                    x.Field<string>(Gen_Name_ID).Trim() == memRow[Payer_ID].ToString().Trim() ||
                                                                    x.Field<string>(Gen_Name_ID).Trim() == memRow[TPA_Broker_ID].ToString().Trim()
                                                                    );
            ContactTbl = ContactTblMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(MEMBER_ID).Trim() == MemberID);
            GenReferenceTbl = GenReferenceTblMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(MEMBER_ID).Trim() == MemberID);
            MemberTbl = MemberTblMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(MEMBER_ID).Trim() == MemberID);



            // Based on Health Coverage
            //Provider , COB



            var loopLevel1 = (from row in LoopOrder.AsEnumerable()
                              where row.Field<int>(HIERARCHY_LEVEL) == 1
                              && !Header.Contains(row.Field<string>(LOOP_ID).Trim())
                              && !Footer.Contains(row.Field<string>(LOOP_ID).Trim())
                              select row);
            foreach (DataRow parentLoop in loopLevel1)
            {
                //Level 1
                //TODO : Need to implement the parent loop functionality
                ParentLoop = Convert.ToString(parentLoop[PARENT_LOOP]);

                string loopIDofLoopOrder = parentLoop[LOOP_ID].ToString();
                LoopID = loopIDofLoopOrder;
                var resultLevel1 = (from row in ValidationElementAttribute.AsEnumerable()
                                    where row.Field<string>(LoopIdSegment).Trim() == loopIDofLoopOrder
                                    select row);

                if (resultLevel1.Any())
                {
                    int maxCount1;
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(parentLoop[Repeat_max])))
                        maxCount1 = maximumCount; //Max_Repitition = NULL means infinite number of repititions allowed; no upper cap
                    else
                        maxCount1 = Convert.ToInt32(parentLoop[Repeat_max]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < maxCount1; i++) //until all the repititions are covered, keep repeating the same loop, else change the parent loop
                    {
                        SkipLine = false;
                        WriteWholeLine(line, i, resultLevel1, writer, memRow);


                        #region Level 2

                        var loopLevel2 = (from row in LoopOrder.AsEnumerable()
                                          where row.Field<int>(HIERARCHY_LEVEL) == 2
                                          && row.Field<string>(PARENT_LOOP).Trim() == loopIDofLoopOrder.Trim()
                                          select row);
                        foreach (DataRow level2 in loopLevel2)
                        {
                            //Level 2
                            //  ChildLoop = Convert.ToString(level2["PARENT_LOOP"]);// 1000C
                            ChildLoop = Convert.ToString(level2[LOOP_ID]);// 1100C
                            LoopID = ChildLoop;
                            var resultLevel2 = (from row in ValidationElementAttribute.AsEnumerable()
                                                where row.Field<string>(LoopIdSegment).Trim() == ChildLoop.Trim()
                                                select row);

                            //var healthCoverageIdList = memberEnrollment.Select(x => x.Field<object>(Health_Coverage_ID)).Distinct().ToList();

                            if (resultLevel2.Any())
                            {
                                int maxCount2;
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(level2[Repeat_max])))
                                    maxCount2 = maximumCount;
                                else
                                    maxCount2 = Convert.ToInt32(level2[Repeat_max]);

                                //Custom Code                                   
                                // maxCount2=  ChildLoop == _2300 ?  healthCoverageIdList.Count :  maxCount2;


                                for (int j = 0; j < maxCount2; j++)
                                {
                                    SkipLine = false;
                                    //Custom Code
                                    //if (ChildLoop == "2300")
                                    //{
                                    //    WriteWholeLine(line, j, resultLevel2, writer, memRow, memberEnrollment.Where(x => x.Field<object>(Health_Coverage_ID) == healthCoverageIdList[j]).Select(x => x));
                                    //}
                                    //else
                                    //{
                                    //WriteWholeLine(line, j, resultLevel2, writer, memRow, memberEnrollment);
                                    //}



                                    WriteWholeLine(line, j, resultLevel2, writer, memRow);

                                    if (HealthCoverageTbl.Any() && HealthCoverageTbl.Count() > j)
                                    {
                                        HealthCoverageID = Convert.ToString(HealthCoverageTbl.ElementAt(j).Field<string>(Health_Coverage_ID)).Trim();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        HealthCoverageID = string.Empty;
                                    }

                                    #region Level 3


                                    var loopLevel3 = (from row in LoopOrder.AsEnumerable()
                                                      where row.Field<int>(HIERARCHY_LEVEL) == 3
                                                      && row.Field<string>(PARENT_LOOP).Trim() == ChildLoop.Trim()
                                                      select row);
                                    foreach (DataRow level3 in loopLevel3)
                                    {
                                        //Level 3
                                        ChildLoopLevel3 = Convert.ToString(level3[LOOP_ID]);
                                        LoopID = ChildLoopLevel3;
                                        var resultLevel3 = (from row in ValidationElementAttribute.AsEnumerable()
                                                            where row.Field<string>(LoopIdSegment).Trim() == ChildLoopLevel3.Trim()
                                                            select row);
                                        if (resultLevel3.Any())
                                        {
                                            CobInfoTbl = CobInfoTblMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(Health_Coverage_ID).Trim() == HealthCoverageID).Select(x => x);
                                            ProviderTbl = ProviderTblMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(Health_Coverage_ID).Trim() == HealthCoverageID).Select(x => x);

                                            LXcounter = 0;
                                            int maxCount3;
                                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(level3[Repeat_max])))
                                                maxCount3 = maximumCount;
                                            else
                                                maxCount3 = Convert.ToInt32(level3[Repeat_max]);
                                            for (int k = 0; k < maxCount3; k++)
                                            {
                                                SkipLine = false;
                                                if (CobInfoTbl.Any() && CobInfoTbl.Count() > k)
                                                {
                                                    CobInfoID = CobInfoTbl.ElementAt(k).Field<string>(COB_ID);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    CobInfoID = Convert.ToString("0");
                                                }

                                                //Not used : uncomment if Provider ID needed.
                                                if (ProviderTbl.Any() && ProviderTbl.Count() > k)
                                                {
                                                    ProviderID = ProviderTbl.ElementAt(k).Field<string>(Provider_ID).Trim();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    ProviderID = string.Empty;
                                                }

                                                WriteWholeLine(line, k, resultLevel3, writer, memRow);


                                                #region Level 4

                                                var loopLevel4 = (from row in LoopOrder.AsEnumerable()
                                                                  where row.Field<int>(HIERARCHY_LEVEL) == 4
                                                                  && row.Field<string>(PARENT_LOOP).Trim() == ChildLoopLevel3.Trim()
                                                                  select row);
                                                foreach (DataRow level4 in loopLevel4)
                                                {
                                                    //Level 4
                                                    ChildLoopLevel4 = Convert.ToString(level4[LOOP_ID]);
                                                    LoopID = ChildLoopLevel4;
                                                    var resultLevel4 = (from row in ValidationElementAttribute.AsEnumerable()
                                                                        where row.Field<string>(LoopIdSegment).Trim() == ChildLoopLevel4.Trim()
                                                                        select row);
                                                    if (resultLevel4.Any())
                                                    {
                                                        int maxCount4;
                                                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(level4[Repeat_max])))
                                                            maxCount4 = maximumCount;
                                                        else
                                                            maxCount4 = Convert.ToInt32(level4[Repeat_max]);
                                                        for (int l = 0; l < maxCount4; l++)
                                                        {
                                                            SkipLine = false;

                                                            WriteWholeLine(line, l, resultLevel4, writer, memRow);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                #endregion
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    #endregion
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }
            // TODO : remove below break
            // break;
        }
        //end of Regeneration
        #endregion
        return line;
    }
```

---

Comment: It really depends on what sort of logic do you do on each level. Sometimes  there are ways to take a different approach to mathematical calculations to reduce nesting. If that is not an option, you could have a look at asynchronous approach. Also consider if each level needs to enumerate the entire collection or can stop as soon as some condition is met.

Comment: You have omitted all relevant informations about what you loop and why you need the nested loops at all. So how can we help to optimize something if we don't know anything about your logic?

Comment: You'll really need to provide more sample code. As @RVid said, it really depends on the contents of your loops.

Comment: The file i am trying to print say is having a blue print of the structure which have these nested loop, so i had to go with nesting .
Eg: Member Details (Level 1)
        Health Coverage (Level 2)
          Provider Information (Level 3)
            BeneFits (Level 4)

So Member details which can have multiple Health Coverage in which each health Coverage can have multiple Provider in which each Provider can have multiple benefits.

hope this help with my situation in a real time example

Comment: Maybe you can process all the information as needed and the write the file in just one loop. Sometimes it helps.

Comment: Are you by any chance using an ORM? In this case you should be looking at prefetching because you are probably generating a lot of database requests.

Comment: "Hence it is taking lot of time. Please suggest me some alternative or how can i optimize my code." - we can't because we don't know what a lot of time is and whether or not it is an appropriate amount of time. Post minimal code that shows the actual performance problem/concern.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović :yes i am prefetching all the records from database and then performing this nested for each.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd : due to confidnetiality i cant share the exact code , but i think i have given you the scenario.
Talking about time so say for 20 Member its taking 7 mins which is very huge

Comment: I don't think that 20 records and related collections (if prefetched, that is) can impose such an impact on operation. Try profiling database and, if it looks reasonable, your code to find out where the time is spent.

Comment: "Due to confidentiality..." you do not need to provide us with your exact data/code, but you can at least provide a mock-up that simulates your situation. What you have provided so far does not give any way to provide any meaningful help. Unfortunately, your problem could be anywhere... It could be the data, the structure of the data, or any number of calculations or transformations of said data that may be happening in any one of those loops. Until we have something to work with, the chances of getting an answer of any value are slim to none.

Comment: @gmiley added the code

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd  code added

Answer (score 0):

if the order of the entries does not matter as in the results of each nested loop dont need to have the structure the foreach source has.

A->B->C->D->E each of those represent a nested loop, you could do it in parallel.

since all data manipulation should be the same, rewrite all foreach as in parallel. save the results to a collection like a ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: SO cuts my answer somehow, dont know what i am doing wrong:
if the order of the entries does not matter as in the results of each nested loop dont need to have the structure the foreach source has.

A->B->C->D->E each of those represent a nested loop, you could do it in parallel.

Comment: since all data manipulation should be the same, rewrite all foreach as in parallel. save the results to a collection like a ConcurrentDictionary<coverage,Concurrent.................
then dump each member dictionary to your writer,

Comment: if you can guess higher up the chain if the member has lots of services, use a priority queue and give the faster ones a higher priority and use another thread for the slower ones, that way, you dont gobble up all the threads/ use multiple queues

Comment: so if i am in Domain E, the order of the Prints, inside of E matter?

Comment: if the prints inside level 4 matter, there is no way to speed things up, the only thing you could do is build a cache of all level 4 prints in parallel (basicly run level 3 in parallel) and put them in a concurrent list and print them sorted out via an id; you could go up as many levels as you like, but doing level 3 in parallel seems to be a good test if you can do it

Comment: Why level 3? And not level 1

Comment: you said the order mattered, if you do level 1 in parallel, you would get output from diffrent level 2 objects mixed -> race condition